# List all table from a SQL query Oracle or a View

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a long SQL query and I want to list all tables that are queried from. How can I do that? (it's not list table from database). The same question for a View that created from SQL script.

> ```
> eg: 
>
> Select * from a1 
> left join a2 on a1.id = a2.id
>
> desired result: a1, a2
> ```

Comment: One way would be to explain plan the SQL, and then query plan_table to get the different objects (tables/indexes...) Though some corner cases may miss some objects (e.g. when the optimizer removes a join due the presence of an FK)

Comment: @gsalem plz show with code/example

Answer (score 0):

After an explain plan, you can use this query to get the tables:

```
with objs as (select distinct object_name,object_type
from plan_table
where object_name is not null
and object_type is not null)
select object_name
from objs 
where object_type='TABLE'
union
select table_name
from user_indexes i join objs o on (o.object_name=i.index_name)
where o.object_type like 'INDEX%';
```

Adapt it to your needs (e.g. if you have different schemas, ....)

Comment: Hi, you should say complete solution, how can I explain plan @gsalem

Comment: I thought that someone who works with an oracle db knows how to at least find the doc. And it would have been easier for you to search for oracle explain plan on the net  than to type your comment. And I think there's no law that mandates full solutions here